# CSS classes not getting applied to html code in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css

I am actually trying to integrate my static HTML pages with TWENTY TWELVE theme

As far as I understood, I need to add my header section into `header.php` and footer to `footer.php`  and for the content part I need to add template and for adding CSS & JS function call need to add them `function.php`

But after doing all this things my CSS classes does not get applied to HTML code which I have added to header section as well as footer section.

After inspecting I came to know my CSS classes are loaded properly but does not get applied.

Comment: I presume making a jsFiddle for this kind of situation would not be trivial, but the least you can do is provide a link to your site and point out an example of which exact style doesn't get applied to which exact element.

Comment: If you can see the classes applied but not taking effect, the styles are being overwritten by a more specific selector...

Comment: @Mr Lister,@War10ck actually it doesnot shows up that part of html at all i need to inspect to see whether it is there in html dom or not i mean to say that part of html code is added to dom but doesnot displays it

Comment: @psi We shouldn't have to visit an external site to debug your problem. Please post relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: @BenFortune The problem is not that there is no code posted here, but that the question is far too vague. With not much more problem description than "my CSS classes does not get applied to HTML code", how can we begin diagnosing the problem? That's why I asked the OP to point out an example of which exact style doesn't get applied to which exact element. Oh well.

Comment: guys problem has been solved its actually one of my css file is hiding major part html code